# Percentage calculation and outputting images from those percentages c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So I am using Visual Studio, I have 4 textboxes, each that will have a number between 1 and 5 in them, and then I have a calculate button, which once clicked will calculate the percentage of these numbers added up, an award is outputted as an image (either gold star (90% or higher), silver star (90-75%), bronze star (75 - 60%) or none). This award is outputted into an image box. I don't really have any direction in how to do this so all help is welcome.

Here is my current code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double dPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(((Convert.ToInt32(txtScore1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore4.Text)) * 20) / 100);//calculates the percentage

        if(dPercentage > 89)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/gold.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else if(dPercentage > 74 && < 90)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/silver.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else (dPercentage > 59 && < 74)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/bronze.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please add Codes which you have tried.

Comment: I really don't know how to calculate the percentages from the textboxes

Comment: my textboxes are just called txtScore1 - 4, I assume i have to calculate the percentage in the calculate button event, not sure where to start

Comment: Kindly update the question with the working code you have so far!

Comment: should be updated

Comment: Dont add the image copy paste -_-

Comment: sorry i fixed it up

Comment: As a note, WPF applications usually implement the MVVM pattern. You should have a view model with the two scores as properties and either an ImageSource property that returns the corresponding image or a MultiBinding with an IMultiValueConverter that returns the image. Besides that, the image files should be assembly resources. Set their Build Action to Resource and load them by Resource File Pack URIs like `pack://application:,,,/Images/gold.png` (without setting on UriKind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the logic errors in the decision making, the percentage calculation is wrong. Try this...

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double dPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(((Convert.ToInt32(txtScore1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore4.Text))) / 20.0) * 100;//calculates the percentage

        if (dPercentage >= 90)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/gold.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else if (dPercentage >= 75)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/silver.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else if (dPercentage >= 60)
        {
            imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/bronze.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else
        {
            imgAward.Source = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Tburn96 So directly within your project folder you have a folder called "Images" which is part of your project, and inside that you have files called "gold.png", "silver.png", and "bronze.png", and all of those are included as part of the project, and if you look at the Properties of each of those files from Solution Explorer then the "Build Action" says "Resource"?

Comment: where do i put the folder in my files? I simply right clicked on the solution and clicked add new folder

Comment: Not the Solution, right-click on the **Project**, Add -> New Folder

Comment: yea thats what i did sorry

Comment: Then right-click on the folder Add -> Existing Item... and pick the files. It should guess "Resource" correctly; but you can check that...

Comment: ok so when i do 5 for all 4 inputs, i get my golden star, however doesnt work for any other

Comment: @Tburn96 Ah, sorry, schoolboy error, the divide needs to be using a "double operator" just edited the answer.

Comment: @Richardissimo no problem!

Answer (score 0):

First your logic here is wrong

```C#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    double dPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(((Convert.ToInt32(txtScore1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtScore4.Text))) / 20.0) * 100;//calculates the percentage

    if(dPercentage >= 90)
    {
        //Percentage is greater than 89
        MessageBox.Show("Eligible For the Gold Award");

        imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/gold.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    else if(dPercentage >= 75)
    {
            //(90-75%)
     MessageBox.Show("Eligible For the Silver Award");
        imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/silver.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    else if (dPercentage >= 60)
    {
            // (75 - 60%)
     MessageBox.Show("Eligible For the Bronze Award");
        imgAward.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/bronze.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }else{
        MessageBox.Show("Not Eligible For the Award");
        }
}}
```